# Swift: ambiguous use of operator '*'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, closures, swift3

Experimenting with an array of closures in Xcode Playgrounds, I receive this error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: closures.playground:11:25: error: ambiguous use of operator '*'
            {x in x * x},
```

I don't see a reason syntactically why this isn't working, but **it should.**

My initial closure is:

```
let f = {(x: Int) -> Int
    in
    return x + 42}
```

I then define an array thus:

```
let closures = [f,
            {(x:Int) -> Int in return x * 2},
            {x in return x - 8},
            {x in x * x}, //This line causes the error.
            {$0 * 42}]
```

Each of these closures conform to `f`'s signature, so is this a bug in Xcode? If not, what's happening?

To dove-tail on that, shouldn't the type be inferred in that one case, just like it is clearly inferred in all other cases?

Edit: In Swift 2.2, this seems to work fine, but I'm using Swift3.

Comment: It seems to work fine if we replace `x * x` with lets say `x * 8`. or multiply with some constant.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari That's true, but `x * x` follows Swift syntax rules and doesn't work, which seems buggy to me.

Comment: I guess its because the compiler is unable to find the type of x variable multiplying with itself as it gives the data type as <error type>. However multiplying with some int constants makes it for the compiler

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Even when I change x to an optional data type, it still has the same error.

Comment: I think it is not inferred when you mutiplied that inside scope

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari and I should add, that it matches the other signatures, all of which work with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Signature matching and type inference are two different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a theory if you're willing to follow along here:

Using your definition of `f`, the following line results in different errors in Swift 2.2 and Swift 3.0:

```
let closures = [f, { $0 * 4.5 },{$0 * 42}]
```

Note the second element is multiplied by a Double, making x's inferred type as Double as well, so the closure signatures don't match.

In Swift 2.2: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

In Swift 3.0: "Heterogenous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional"

This seems to indicate that the Swift 3.0 compiler can recognize the possibility of different closure signatures that could be downcasted to `Any` as the homogenous element type.

In your example:

```
let closures = [f,
        {(x:Int) -> Int in return x * 2},
        {x in return x - 8},
        {x in x * x}, //This line causes the error.
        {$0 * 42}]
```

The line that causes the error has no explicit type for `x`.  Swift 3.0 allows for the possibility that `x` may be some other type, e.g. a Double, Float, etc. and that the whole array may be intended as having the type `[Any]` instead of `[(Int)->Int]`.  So by not declaring any explicit type for `x` in this location, or for `closures` as a whole, it's not clear to the compiler which version of the `*` function should be selected.  Maybe those `x`'s are both Doubles? Floats? Since the type of the `closures` array isn't explicit and the type of `x` isn't explicit, the compiler can't be sure which version of `*` should be used there and what the operand types are.

Thus, you can fix the error by either making the type of the array explicit, i.e.:

```
let closures:[(Int)->Int] = [f,
        {(x:Int) -> Int in return x * 2},
        {x in return x - 8},
        {x in x * x}, //No more error.
        {$0 * 42}]
```

Or, by making the type of `x` inside the closure explicit, i.e.:

```
let closures = [f,
        {(x:Int) -> Int in return x * 2},
        {x in return x - 8},
        {(x:Int) in x * x}, //No more error.
        {$0 * 42}]
```

In the other closures, the other operand opposite the `x` is sufficient for the compiler to infer the type of `x`, but in the closure that generates the error, there is nothing that will conclusively nail down the type.

Again, it seems like this worked in Swift 2.2, because Swift 2.2 would not extrapolate heterogenous arrays as being of type `[Any]` and so assumed that all closures must have the same type.  In Swift 3, there seems to be some fuzzier possibilities allowed, which makes the compiler less certain of your intent.

At least that's my theory  :)

Comment: That is a good observation, though in Swift2.2, these closures work as is. So this is why I'm confused.

Comment: @NonCreature0714  I dug in a little more and changed my answer to reflect a _theory_ as to why it works in Swift 2.2 but not Swift 3.0

Comment: I'll take a good look at it tomorrow morning when I'm at my laptop!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it sounds correct but the x variable has no type. Neither it inferred any type from any other constant by operating.

It is **<< error type >>**. So the compiler is finding is ambiguos

[image]